# How to subscribe to events in OnEnable when the object that is subscribed to is initialized in Start?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When using (C#) events in Unity, `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` are used to subscribe and unsubscribe to the events, so callbacks won't be triggered on disabled objects. However, sometimes the object that is subscribed to can be initialized only at `Start` (that is called after `OnEnable`) which means that when `OnEnable` is called for the first time, you cannot subscribe to the object as it's not initialized yet (later `OnEnable`s will work fine). One fix for that, as also described [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/awake-onenable-start-not-good.93788/), is to use a flag "`hasStarted`", so the first time you will subscribe at `Start` and set it to true, but any other time the object is enabled you will subscribe using `OnEnable` (making sure that `hasStarted` is true, that is, it's not the first `OnEnable` call).

However, that seems really ugly, especially since this situation is not rare at all. And I wonder if there are any other ways to get such a functionality without using a one-time flag.

Answer (score 0):

The methods go Awake->OnEnable->Start so you can do the event subscription inside OnEnable only. It's a bit convoluted to my liking as well, but you won't need any additional flags.

Just tested it for UI Toolkit because I had a similar issue (I was subscribing in Awake for button clicks so when setting back to active I had no more event subscriptions since Awake wasn't called again and OnDisabled unsubscribed automatically). (MainMenu->Settings->MainMenu situation).